# C MPI program taking forever to start

Tags: c, debugging, mpi

I have a project that I've been working on but have hit a road block. The game we have to implement is the [game of morra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morra_(game)). Basically, every process is a player and then we specify how many rounds of the game to do. So to run the program we use the following command:

mpiexec -n  ./morra

I believe I have the program logic down for this as it works fine for smaller amounts of players. I was testing with 4, 6, 10, 25 players and everything was good. However, the requirements of the project included testing up to 500 or 1000 players.

When I tried this, my program just hangs and doesn't even start. I put a printf statement as the first thing after main() and ran the game with 500 players and after a minute or two it finally printed out the statement and ran the program. What is going on here? Is the system waiting and trying to allocate enough resources to continue?

Also, another requirement is to run the program on a cluster of nodes we have available to us. I created the host file and made sure i could login keyless into all of the servers and ran it, yet I had the same wait time problem and often the server's would disconnect. I understand that there might be rules on the servers that kick someone off under certain conditions but that still doesn't explain when it does not kick me off, the program won't start either.

Wondering if anyone can provide any insight on these problems. I can provide code/sections of code I've written or the general layout of my program or any information I might have left out.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring your system performance to check things like memory use?

Comment: You will get better answers if you post some relevant code.

Comment: @Bwebb I wasn't sure what to post as I don't think this is my code that is preventing it from starting. I put a print statement as the first thing that happens when the program starts, before MPI is even initialized and the print statement does not occur, which means my program isn't even starting. Is there a specific segment you would like to see?

Comment: @paddy Just tried this. As soon as I start the program, the processes are shown (500/1000 of them). Each process has <2% CPU, and each process has 0% memory. The program however isn't running yet (after ~40 seconds) and hasn't printed out the print statement the line after main(), so each program hasn't actually started.

Comment: are you trying to `mpirun -n 1000 ./morra` ? if yes how many cores are available (local host or total cores per your machinefile ? try to simply `mpirun -n 1000 hostname` and check how long it takes. which MPI (vendor & version) are you running ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I tried mpirun, but no difference. I have always been using mpiexec, if that makes a difference. each computer I'm running on has 4 cores. mpirun -n 1000 hostname runes fine, not able to start though as a program isn't specified. It still reports back quickly that it failed to start 1000 processes because not program was specified. MPICH2

Comment: On many Linux distributions, you could run into process limits. For example, to be able to run `mpiexec -n 1000 true`, I need to first adjust the limits using e.g `ulimit -n 8192 -s 1024`. (On this Core i5-7200U laptop, `mpiexec -n 1000 true` takes about 4.5 seconds wall clock time.) Note that `true` (`/bin/true`) is a simple program that does nothing.

Comment: sorry for the typo, it should be `mpirun -np 1000 hostname` or `mpiexec -n 1000 hostname` (but definitely not `mpiexec -n ./morra` as written in the question)

Comment: @NominalAnimal The limit is set to unlimited

Comment: @NominalAnimal When running the program in valgrind, I get spammed with this: warning: invalid file descriptor 199990/5, with the last digit being 0-5. This happens when the program does run correctly with only 10 processes starting and also when running with 1000 processes. However, the difference is 10 finishes after spamming that and 1000 just spams it for a long time.

Comment: @DevinK: By process limits, I didn't mean the number of processes, but any per-process limit. The stack size (`-s`) and the maximum number of open files (`-n`) are the most typical ones you hit. You definitely should use at least `ulimit -s 1024`, to limit the amount of virtual memory needed for stacks.

Comment: @NominalAnimal -s = 8192, -n = 200000, however I cannot change these values as this is a university server I don't have permissions to change that kind of stuff on

Comment: @DevinK: You are allowed to temporarily set e.g `ulimit -s 1024`, because it only reduces the default stack size. It only affects the current session, and will be reset to default when you next log in. What you are not allowed to do, is raise the limits. (You are allowed to *try*; your shell will just tell you you cannot, because you don't have the privileges.)

Comment: I would expect to see a filename and line number in the messages from valgrind.

Comment: @user3386109 "==3609== Warning: invalid file descriptor 199990 in syscall close()" That's all it says, it just repeats that

Comment: @DevinK: It looks like some part just makes a pre-emptive `close()` on all descriptors first, nothing to worry about. I wrote a trivial MPI test program with `MPI_Barrier()` and outputting the rank and size of MPI_COMM_WORLD, and while `mpiexec -n 150 ./example` runs in three seconds of wall clock time, `mpiexec -n 200 ./example` takes about fifteen seconds, and `mpiexec -n 250 ./example` a minute or so; my single four-core system with 16 GiB of RAM just cannot handle that many MPI processes passing messages to and fro. Don't you have a cluster to submit jobs to?

Comment: @NominalAnimal I do, I have 8 computers that I specified in the hostfile that can be used to run the program on. However, when I do this, the same problem happens where it just takes a long long long time to start. I'm not really sure why

Comment: @DevinK: Then do what I did: write a trivial test program, and check that first. If you use barriers, include one.  Include some output as well. That will give you a basis benchmark to compare against.

Comment: @NominalAnimal running "mpiexec -n 10 ./test" runs under 1-2 seconds, however when running: "mpiexec --hostfile ./hostfile -n 10 ./test" it takes >20 seconds (on 4 nodes) to finish. I have a good connection to the servers, and I'm able to logon to each one very fast (so I'm guessing no bandwidth problems). What does that tell us?

Comment: do you have firewalls ?

Comment: @DevinK: Maybe bandwidth, connectivity, or load issues between the cluster machines? I'd next write a minimal test case where root node sends a short message (say, just an int) to each other node (who immediately respond back), in turn, and measure the roundtrip times (using eg. `MPI_Wtime()`) on the root node for each, separately. After measuring them all, print them out. If they're in the millisecond or sub-millisecond range, the net between the nodes is OK. Otherwise, the net or the nodes themselves is overloaded or is otherwise wonky.